# How to clear Session when navigating away from one page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, page-lifecycle

I googled this about 1/2 a hour no hit's. Scenario is that, dynamic scripts are saved in string builder whose `"string"` representation is stored in session. It just happens that when user navigates away from one page to another the script[from session] gets registered using `"RegisterStartupScript"`. The script is registered in PreRender event of the Page. So i would like to clear this script in session while the page navigates away btw rule out a option to create another session variable and clear previous one. It's a overhead :(

Comment: Did you at all find a solution for this . I have a similar problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you storing this in Session, do you need to maintain this script in between GET requests?

If only postbacks are relevant you could store it in viewstate as this is maintained only when doing a postback.

If you want this string to be available on GET requests too you might want to introduce a different variable which has an identifier identifying the page for which the script is generated. If the requested page doesn't match the control variable you will have to generate a new script.

Comment: `Why are you storing this in Session?` well these scripts are dynamically generated based on database data. The script is attached to gridview rows for Ajax Editing, Updating using webservice. No way am i going to put it inside ViewState. 3rd option comes under generating new key's so BIG NO

Comment: I'm not saying you should generate a new key, you could store all the scripts in the same session variable but just add a simple control variable containing an identifier of the page.

Comment: that's what i currently have in mind now, you have any other idea??

Comment: I don't think you've got a lot more options :)

Comment: I had no other answers hence had to accept something nearer to the answer as the 'answer'

Answer (score 0):

You may use the JavaScript `onUnload()` and call an AJAX service, that will clear the server side session.

Comment: So `onUnLoad` executes only on navigating away or also a postback ??

Answer (score 0):

How is the user navigating away from the page? Can't you use an ASP.NET button instead of a hyperlink, and then do a Redirect in code once you have cleared your session variable?

```
protected void btnDoSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Value"] = String.Empty;
    Response.Redirect(strURL, false);
}
```

OR You could add a variable in the query string and check it in the Page_Load event of the target page:

```
Webform1.aspx?reset=true
```

Comment: the redirect is done via menu. The menuitem doesn't  do a postback, even though if it does i don't want to postback for navigating away

Comment: What about adding an option to the menu item so that it appears in the QueryString and resetting the Session variable in the Page_Load event of the target page? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: not the best of idea when you got only bunch of pages and SEO is of importance. Seems there is no way out other than using viewstate, another variable as the state holder[holds the state of script] thanks for the answers Winston appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Since I cant comment yet, use onUnload().

It fires on full postbacks too. Ajax postbacks dont fire!

What you need to do, is guaranty inside the onUload function that you only clear the session when you want. Like setting a variable isPostBack to true before the postbacks so onUnload sees the variable and doenst send a request to clear the session.