# Remove content of asp.net session while navigating onto another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, dataset

I have a session variable that I am using on a page. I know that sessions should be used for the purpose
    of storing data between different pages of a website, but I have a big dataset to store and I am using a session instead of a view state.

I would like to empty the session when I navigate to another page.

Is there a way I can do it ?

I tried setting the session variable to null on the PageUnload event, but thats not what I want.

I would like to set the session variable to null while the page is navigated to another page.

Please let me know.

Comment: On the pages where you are navigating, clear the session.

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421470/how-to-clear-session-when-navigating-away-from-one-page

Comment: How many pages are using this session? As in, how do you know you no longer need the session or that they navigate to a page that doesn't need it?

Comment: I use the session only on this (one) page. I dont need the session as soon as I navigate away from this page.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to detect when user leaves the page - you have to do this from the client-side. Handle `onbeforeunload` event and make an AJAX call to clear session variable.

But this is an overkill. Consider refactoring the code to store in session smaller amount of data and only that is used between different pages.

Comment: and how to remove a session variable content ?

Comment: You will make an AJAX call to server-side code. And in that server-side code do a `Session.Remove("var");`

Answer (score 0):

On the page you have navigated to you can clear a session variable as follows:

```
Session.Remove("Name");
```

To abandon the session completely:

```
Session.Abandon();
```

Comment: and how to handle the "leaving page" ?

Comment: I have a lot of pages that I can navigate to . I dont think in my case I can add the Session.Remove on every page of my website.